# how to detect specific versions of browser

Tags: javascript, browser, navigator

I wanted to check if browser is supported or not,
I wanted to check the specific browser with browser versions,

How to check if Safari (12.1+) or not ?
How to check if Edge (80+) or not ?

I have a function written wanted to modify that to achieve the same..

```
function isBrowserSupported() {
    let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    // let webrtcDetectedBrowser;
    // need to check if should check OS also
    let isBrowserSupported = false;
    if (userAgent.match(/chrome|chromium|crios/i) || (userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)) || (userAgent.match(/safari/i)) || (userAgent.match(/edg/i))) {
        isBrowserSupported = true;
    } 
    return isBrowserSupported;
}
```

isBrowserSupported() should return true when browser is:

```
Chrome (MacOS/Windows/Android)
Firefox (MacOS/Windows)
Edge (80+)(Windows)
Safari (12.1+) ((MacOS/iPadOS/iOS)
```

navigator.userAgent return's this -

```
> navigator.userAgent
< "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15"
```

Comment: Try to avoid checking for browser versions. Check for the specific features that you need.

Answer (score 1):

i hope **`navigator.userAgentData`** will solve your problem.
you can use **`navigator.platform`** for finding platform

```js
console.log(navigator.userAgentData)
console.log(navigator.platform)
```

Comment: (navigator.userAgentData) is not available in firefox and safari.. it's undefined..

Comment: that's unfortunate, your function is pretty good in my opinion and why don't you add  regex match for platform as well

Comment: try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect.js

Comment: my ask was to get the version details also because some time few features are not support below some versions..

Comment: I should use, navigator.userAgent output to check version is it good idea ? but chrome gives - Chrome/97.0.4692.99 but safari gives - Version/15.2  how to have unique way to check version..

Comment: i am not sure if there is an alternate way for this other than navigator.userAgent output,
if you are concerned about the features why don't you use a function for validate availability of those feature inside of a try block?
in case of error function will  return false and we can notify user about browser incompatibility

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241606/discussion-between-anirudhsanthosh-and-javascript-coder).